# Back slash to get name space

Tags: php

So, in my router.php file I create an object of `runApp` class using namespace. Everything work fine.

```
namespace Router;

// app/routes.php

$runApp= new \Core\runApp();
```

In this case back slash(new \Core\runApp()) means that I need to look from my namespace `Router` and try find `runApp` class in `Core` namespace.

But also, I can use link in this way:

```
namespace Router;

use Core\runApp;

// app/routes.php

$runApp= new runApp();
```

But, why in last case I do not need to set `\` befor namespace(use Core\runApp)??

Comment: Because `use Core\runApp;` is telling PHP what namespace it should be using as an alias for runApp - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php see note `Note that for namespaced names (fully qualified namespace names containing namespace separator, such as Foo\Bar as opposed to global names that do not, such as FooBar), the leading backslash is unnecessary and not recommended, as import names must be fully qualified, and are not processed relative to the current namespace. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that for namespaced names (fully qualified namespace names containing namespace separator, such as Foo\Bar as opposed to global names that do not, such as FooBar), the leading backslash is unnecessary and not recommended, as import names must be fully qualified, and are not processed relative to the current namespace.

From [PHP - Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

When you use the `use` keyword, namespaces are not relative, they have to be fully qualified.
Whereas, in all other cases, it's relative to the current namespace.

Answer (score 1):

By using the "use" statement you defined an alias for your class "runapp". 
So it's available inside your PHP file.

You only need a full namespaced class, if you want to address a class "outside" and it's not defined in a use statement (aliased before).

Think of use-statement as shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is used for the global namespace.

In your first example, you are not in the global namespace, you're in the `Router` namespace. If you want to use a class from another namespace, you can either :

- Specify the full class name (with its namespace) (example 1)
- or use the class' namespace (example 2)

If you wrote in the 2nd example `$runApp = new \runApp()`, you would have used the runApp class from the global namespace, which doesn't exist.

It is usefull when you have 2 classes with the same name. Example :

```
use \Fooo\Bar;

$a = new \Foo\Bar(); // $a is a \Foo\Bar
$b = new Bar(); // $b is a \Fooo\Bar
```